# Script inside bash shell thats inside another bash shell

Tags: bash, shell, scripting

I'm trying to run a simple program

```
#!/bin/bash
bash
echo "Hello World"
```

But the program only gets as far as the 'bash' command on line 2. Why can't the program run line 3? The program terminates at the bash input

```
bash-3.2$
```

Is there another line I need to add so the program can print out "Hello World" ? Keep in mind I do understand I am already in a bash shell, but I still don't understand this error.

Comment: It's not terminated. It's just waiting for you to do something with the `bash` shell the script started. What exactly do you want to achieve?

Comment: I'm not looking to do anything specific really, I just wanted to know why it wont echo Hello World and what I can fix so it *will* echo Hello World

Comment: Remove the `bash`.

Comment: You could have bash actually run something, eg `bash -c "echo why?"`

Comment: Line 3 doesn't run because it won't run until the `bash` you started on line 2 terminates.  `bash` is no different to any other program you might run on line 2....line 3 won't run until the program on line 2 finishes (unless you cause it to run in the background with `&`)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you're running this from a command prompt in a terminal, you're running **three** instances of bash:

1. The interactive bash running in the terminal.
2. The bash instance that runs your script.
3. The bash instance that is invoked by the second line of the script.

In your script, you invoke `bash` with no argument, so it reads commands from its standard input. Since the input is coming from a terminal, you get an interactive shell, that prints a prompt and so on.

Once you exit from instance #3, the script (instance #2) continues to the next line and prints `Hello World`. After this the script terminates and you're back to your original command prompt (instance #1).